# Macro to save spreadsheet requiring recovery attempt after reopening excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I've been building an excel form for my employees to fill out.  The form is primarily information gathering.  I've put some macro checking in the back ground to make it easier to ensure everything is done.  I have reused a saving macro from previous excel macros and am currently getting an error that I have no idea what is causing it. After saving, and  reopening the document provides this error message

[image]

The saving macro has worked previously and the only difference is that my new macro has VB code in "This Workbook" and on "Sheet 1" instead of modules.  My question is, what is causing this error?  Is it my saving Function or the set up of my macro?

```
    If SaveLocations <> vbNullString Then
        If Right(SaveLocations, 1) <> "\" And 
        InStr(Right(SaveLocations, 10), ".") = 0 Then
            SaveLocations = SaveLocations & "\"
        Else
        End If
        
        If FileFormatValue = 51 Then
            MacroWb.SaveAs Filename:=SaveLocations & RFC_FileName & _ 
            ".xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=FileFormatValue, CreateBackup:=False
        Else
            MacroWb.SaveAs Filename:=SaveLocations & RFC_FileName & 
            ".xlsm", _
            FileFormat:=FileFormatValue, CreateBackup:=False
        End If
    Else
        fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="", _ 
        FileFilter:= _
            " Excel Macro Free Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & _
            " Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," & _
            " Excel 2000-2003 Workbook (*.xls), *.xls," & _
            " Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", _
            FilterIndex:=2, Title:="Save Report To...")
        
        If fname <> False Then
            Select Case LCase(Right(fname, Len(fname) - 
            InStrRev(fname, ".", , 1)))
                Case "xls"
                    FileFormatValue = 56
                Case "xlsx"
                    FileFormatValue = 51
                Case "xlsm"
                    FileFormatValue = 52
                Case "xlsb"
                    FileFormatValue = 50
                Case Else
                    FileFormatValue = 0
            End Select
            
            If FileFormatValue = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Sorry, unknown file extension."
            Else
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, _ 
                FileFormat:=FileFormatValue, CreateBackup:=False
            End If
        Else
        End If
    End If

I didn't know how to exactly search for this error, but thought this community would have some suggestions.  Thanks in Advance.
```

Comment: Providing your code would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, hopefully what I've added will be able to find the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that the error was due to the Data Validation that I had on my document.  The work around was to save the Drop Down list values in a column and reference it instead of populating it.